# Function in Meteor.js always returns False when wrapped inside another Function

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a function in Meteor.js which does not behave as expected when I wrap it inside another function. In the example provided below,
I use the "if OnlyBank()" function twice: In one instance, the "if onlyBank()" function is simply dropped inside HTML. (see figure 1)
This works, and returns True/False as expected. 
However, when I put this function inside another function (specifically, the "if currentUser" function) it always returns false. (see figure 2)
I suspect  this may be a problem with local/global scope, but I do not know how to fix this problem. Can anyone provide any help?

I am new to Meteor and stack overflow.

Javascript

```
Template.body.helpers({
  onlyBank() {
    return Banks.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()}, Banks.accountNumber:{"$exists":false}, Banks.routingNumber:{"$exists": false});
  },
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    {{> loginButtons}}
    {{#if onlyBank}}
      True
    {{else}}
      False
    {{/if}} <!-- Figure 1. This if statement will retun True when the onlyBank's conditions are met -->
    <div class="row">
      {{#if currentUser}}
      <div class="col s8">
        {{#if onlyBank}}
          True
        {{else}}
          False
        {{/if}} <!-- Figure 2. This if statement ALWAYS returns false -->
      </div>
      <div class="col s4">
        {{> banks}}
      </div>
      {{else}}
        YOU NEED TO BE LOGGED IN FIRST
      {{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if I got it right, the `Meteor.userId` is not a function.

You should use: `{userId: Meteor.userId}`

Maybe you give this a try:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  onlyBank() {
    return (Meteor.userId !== undefined) && (Banks.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId}, Banks.accountNumber:{"$exists":false}, Banks.routingNumber:{"$exists": false}) !== undefined);
  },
});
```

This will return always a boolean value